# Scrambled Xen Console on dom0

Tags: ubuntu, centos, console, xen

I installed Xen using the recommended procedure on Ubuntu's site using motherboard Supermicro X7SBL-LN2 and Ubuntu 13.04 amd64. After the installing it and rebooting my console looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UbZt7Gix2Q I've had this happen also with CentOS 6 as well. Everything on the server works fine but the console is unusable. If I switch back to the stock kernel it goes back to normal and I can use the console again but then I can't use Xen. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04. Any help troubleshooting this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Supermicro about the problem and they gave me a beta BIOS for the motherboard to try. Surprisingly it actually fixed the problem. Since the BIOS isn't posted on their site I'll just leave a link here to it in case anyone else is having this problem. Use BIOS at your own risk as it is a beta BIOS.

http://geo.animounted.net/X7SBL1.113.zip